# linking values of array to another

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have 2 arrays - one array is coming from the database, another from external json:

```
$album = array( 'author' => 'John', 'id' => '1', 'title' => 'great trip', 'url' => 'http://somelink/index.php?view=show&id=13');

$likes = array( 'link' => 'http://somelink/index.php?view=show&id=13', 'likes' => '30', 'name' => 'great trip');
```

I would like to display the number of likes in the correct album.
What is the best way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: What's the correlation supposed to be? The `link` key?

Comment: This looks like something that should be done in your original database query using a GROUP BY clause.

Comment: well one array is coming from the database, another from external json

Comment: It looks like all you need to do is print `$likes['likes']` - there's not enough context here to tell how to do this. Are you getting the JSON in PHP, or are you calling it in page with, say JavaScript? Also, in your individual page are you doing this multiple times or just once?

Comment: I am getting JSON in PHP and converting it to PHP object with json_decode function. After that I use foreach statement to get the values. But I don't know how exactly to link 2 arrays together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your question is somewhat vague, I'll say that in general, the easiest way to merge two arrays on a specific common element is to use the common element as key:

```
$array1 = array(
    array('id' => 1, 'foo' => 'bar'),
    array('id' => 2, 'foo' => 'baz')
);

$array2 = array(
    array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'John'),
    array('id' => 3, 'name' => 'Jack')
);

$merged = array();

foreach ($array1 as $element) {
    $merged[$element['id']] = $element;
}

foreach ($array2 as $element) {
    if (isset($merged[$element['id']])) {
        $merged[$element['id']] += $element;
    } else {
        $merged[$element['id']] = $element;
    }
}
```

`$merged[$element['id']]` can only exist once, so you can use it to merge the two arrays.

Comment: So in my case, I will have to to throw if statement - if $album['title'] equals $likes['name'] then merge values 'likes' the way you described. So I have to create the table 'likes' in my database, in order to merge them, right?